# How to import a CSV?

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

I've got a CSV file that looks like this:

```
id, name
0, A.D. TRAMONTANA
1, Abarth
2, Abbot-Detroit
3, AC
...
```

I'm trying to import it into my table via phpPgAdmin.

It gives me this error:

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  column "id, name" of relation "app_vehiclemake" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "public"."app_vehiclemake" ("id, name") VALUES (...
                                                ^

In statement:
INSERT INTO "public"."app_vehiclemake" ("id, name") VALUES ('0, A.D. TRAMONTANA')
```

It looks like it's quoting `"id, name"` as one column name. Not really sure why... what format should my CSV be in? Can't find any documentation on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP [**`fgetcsv()`**](https://www.php.net/fgetcsv) function, which is often used to read a line from a CSV file, expects :

- `,` as a delimiter between fields
- `"` as enclosure, for each data of each field.

So maybe just putting double-quotes arround each piece of data would work ?

Something like this, I'd say :

```
"id","name"
"0","A.D. TRAMONTANA"
"1","Abarth"
"2","Abbot-Detroit"
"3","AC"
```

*(Well, not sure... But might be worth a try ?)*

Comment: I think you're right... but I could have sworn it was working *without* quotes before. A space after the comma wouldn't hurt any, would it?